# Need help with regex replace in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have a string which includes links of this pattern:

```
<a href="http://randomurl.com/random_string;url=http://anotherrandomurl.com/">xxxx</a>
```

i want to remove "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/random_string;url=" and keep the rest of the string, leaving at the end

```
<a href="http://anotherrandomurl.com/">xxxx</a>
```

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Can you post what have your tried?

Comment: You have not posted any code or previous attempt, and we can't possibly entertain one question per need of a regular expression. If you can edit your question to show the regex you tried, it will gain answers that actually _help people understand regular expressions_. Please flag your question for moderator attention if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$new_link = preg_replace('/<a href="(?:.+);url=([^"]+)">/', '<a href="$1">', $url);
```

Comment: `?:` makes this a non-capturing subpattern

Comment: This will fail if the tag has any other attributes, or different amounts of whitespace, or if the URL is quoted with `'` instead of `"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods for achieving your desired result. An alternative from `regex` would be to find the occurence of `url=` using [strpos](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and remove those characters and the preceeding characters as well.

Comment: +1 for a solution that will be more robust and easier than a regex

Answer (score 1):

### This is trickier than you think, and I urge you to [avoid using regex for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Instead, you should use an HTML parser to find all `<a>` tags in the document, then split their `href` attributes on `;url=` and keep only the last part.

However, if you **must** use a regex, the following should work for most well-formed HTML:

```
preg_replace('/(<\s*a\s[^>]*href=)(["\'])(?:[^\1]*;url=)([^\1]*)(\1[^>]*>)/i', "$1$2$3$4", $url)
```

Explanation:

```regex
(<\s*a\s[^>]*\bhref=) # <a, optionally followed by other attributes, and then href. Whitespace is ignored. This will be captured in backreference $1.
(["\'])               # Either " or ' to enclose the href value. This will be captured in $2 for matching later.
(?:[^\1]*;url=)       # Any number of URLs followed by ";url=". This will be thrown out.
([^\1]*)              # This is the URL you want to keep. It will keep matching until the end of the quotes. This will be captured into $3.
(\1[^>]*>)            # The remainder of the <a> tag, including any other attributes. This is captured in $4.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_link = preg_replace('~(\shref=")[^"]+?(?<=;url=)~', '$1', $url);
```